# How to clone a online function to a local file

Tags: r

This might be a very basic question, as I am making first code in R (using RStudio). I have have replicated the code in this [page](https://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/classical-technical-patterns/). I want to modify the function in the zip [file](http://www.systematicportfolio.com/sit.gz) that is being included by the code:

```
con = gzcon(url('http://www.systematicportfolio.com/sit.gz', 'rb'))
    source(con)
close(con)
```

Is there a way that I can modify/copy the code in the zip file. I want to load it as a part of my R code (rather than include as a zip through url) and change it. For example, can I copy-paste the functions of the zip code in my local file, and thus can change the code and test quickly.

Comment: Sure open `sit.gz` with your file/archive manager and copy the `code.r` file to a local folder so that you can modify it.

Comment: If for some reason you want to do it programmatically instead, you can use `readLines()` on the connection to fetch the contents, and `writeLines()` should you then want to write to a local plain text file (using a second connection).

Comment: Thanks guys. Didn't realise it was so elementary. Got it working by extracting code.r and including in source("path to code. R").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comment of Paul, the answer was simple:

1. Download the sit.gz file. Unzip it to get code.r file.
2. Change the following code:

con = gzcon(url('http://www.systematicportfolio.com/sit.gz', 'rb'))

```
source(con)
close(con)
```

to

```
source("local path to code.r") # remember to use '/' instead of windows default '\'
```

3. It works.